# CIRadialGradient reduces image size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-image

After applying CIRadialGradient to my image it gets reduced in width by about 20%.

```
guard let image = bgImage.image, let cgimg = image.cgImage else {
    print("imageView doesn't have an image!")
    return
}
let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage:cgimg)

guard let radialMask = CIFilter(name:"CIRadialGradient") else {
    return
}

guard let maskedVariableBlur = CIFilter(name:"CIMaskedVariableBlur") else {
    print("CIMaskedVariableBlur does not exist")
    return 
}
maskedVariableBlur.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

maskedVariableBlur.setValue(radialMask.outputImage, forKey: "inputMask")
guard let selectivelyFocusedCIImage = maskedVariableBlur.outputImage else {
    print("Setting maskedVariableBlur failed")
    return
}


bgImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: selectivelyFocusedCIImage)
```

To clarify, `bgImage` is a `UIImageView`.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Without RadialMask:

[image]

With RadialMask:

[image]

With the difference that on my physical iPhone the smaller image is aligned to the left.

Comment: Can you post the image before and after applying the filters?

Comment: Yes I've just editted my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to explicitly state how big the image is by using a `CIContext` and creating a specifically sized CGImage instead of simply using `UIImage(ciImage:)`. Try this, assuming your inputImage is called `coreGraphics`:

```
let ciCtx = CIContext()
let cgiig = ctx.createCGImage(selectivelyFocusedCIImage, from: coreImage.extent)
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgIMG!)
```

A few notes....

(1) I pulled this code out from an app I'm wrapping up. This is untested code (including the forced-unwrap), but the concept of what I'm doing is solid.

(2) You don't explain a lot of what you are trying to do, but when I see a variable named `selectivelyFocusedCIImage` I get concerned that you may be trying to use CoreImage in a more interactive way than "just" creating one image. If you want "near real-time" performance, render the CIImage in either a (deprecated as of iOS 12) `GLKView` or an `MTKView` instead of a `UIImageView`. The latter only uses the CPU where the two former use the GPU.

(3) Finally, a word of warning on `CIContexts` - they are expensive to create! Usually you can code it such that there's only one context that can be shared by everything n your app.

Comment: This really solved the problem thank you! My purpose was to add a blur but since the image is already blurred it's hard to see. But now that it is solved I can play around with it and make it better. I'm just not sure about how it solved the problem.

Comment: I honestly cannot comment on why `UIImage(ciImage:)` sometimes takes liberties with things, but using the method I described works because (1) it works *only* with a CoreImage - CIImage, CIContext, etc. - and then (2) renders the final CIImage in the `extent` you need. Note that `CIRadialGradient` *could* use an actual `inputImage` of "something" but the output is actually meant to be use as something else - in your case a mask. In my case? I want an output CIImage of **it** but needed an "image size", so my input image is a black CIImage with a particular user-defined extent.

Comment: In *your* case - based on personal experience - I knew that you needed to make your CIImage a specific size (the original image). While blur filters *will* distort the size of the output image, a gradient filter? That was new to me. BUT, using a CIContext to size the output isn't. Remember, a CIImage isn't *really* an image. It's a "recipe". Some filters give you a single pixel output (yes, pixel, not point). How you choose to make this "recipe" what you want is where I think using `UIImage(ciImage:)` breaks down... BADLY. It's a shortcut that just works until it doesn't!

Comment: The size difference happens because the blur filter changes the (virtual) extend of the image. Check my answer—you can easily fix that without creating a `CIContext` every time.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the documentation, it's a mask that being applied to the image:
[image]

Docs: [CIRadialGradient](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIRadialGradient)

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case indeed. But how do I solve this problem and keep the original size instead?

Comment: Also this is a `RadialGradient`, not a `RadialMask`

Comment: It's is a gradient but it treats your image as mask. The same link from documentation leads us to parameters that could be customized: `inputRadius1` and `inputColor1` do seem to be as candidates to play around with.

Comment: I did play around with those but unfortunately it doesn't change anything beside the blur effect.

Answer (score 0):

The different sizes are caused by the kernel size of the blur filter:

The blur filter needs to sample a region around each pixel. Since there are no pixels beyond the image bounds, Core Image reduces the `extend` of the result image by half the kernel size (blur radius) to signal that for those pixels there is not enough information for a proper blur.

However, you can tell Core Image to treat the border pixels as extending infinitely in all directions so that the blur filter gets enough information even on the edges of the image. Afterwards you can crop the result back to the original dimension.

In your code, just change the following two lines:

```
maskedVariableBlur.setValue(coreImage.clampedToExtent(), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

bgImage.image = UIImage(ciImage: selectivelyFocusedCIImage.cropped(to:coreImage.extend))
```